# how do I always keep my html element stick to bottom of parent element,I am using overflow:hidden and giving height implicitly to parent element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making a Keeper App using React, In this app user adds notes which gets displayed on screen. Now the thing is **I want the note to have implicit height:150px and use overflow:auto so that user can view his note content by scrolling**.Then I have added a delete button on bottom-right corner of note, **I want this delete button to always stick to bottom-right corner  even if user scrolls the note**.You can see the image attached below:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/189671520@N03/50250935391/in/dateposted/
Note 2:When user has not yet scrolled the note,the button apears to stick to buttom and works fine.
Note 3:When the user scrolls thats where the problem begins, the delete button is moving up along with the text too, I want that delete button always to be sticked to be Right Hand Side Bottom Corner irrespective of user's scrolling.

The HTML for the Notes is:

```
<div className="note">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <button onClick={deleteNoteInNote}>
        {" "}
        <DeleteIcon />{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
```

The CSS for notes is

```
.note {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 16px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.note h1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.note p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.note button {
  color: #f5ba13;
  border: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

The issue is regarding desktop viewport only cause below width:726px  I have removed the height:150px and replaced it with height:max-content.
**I want to use Bootstrap CDN only**
***Please if possible don't suggest answers which use ReactBootstrap npm package*** 
Thanks for the help , in advance :D

Comment: please make a codesandbox snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521776/13930763  credits= E C(He did all the heavy lifting)

Comment: great.give him upvote and accept his answer.

Comment: I did but my bad :( due to "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: here u go.i increased your score.now you can put tick marks.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 Means a lot to a newbie like me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the note div in another div. Give the new div (parent) a relative positioning. Give the button in the child div an absolute position.

THis should solve your problem.

I made a JSFiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/koder613/18dt3yhL/8/

HTML(JSX):

```
<div className="noteParent">
  <div className="note">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <p>{props.content}</p>
        <button onClick={deleteNoteInNote}>
          {" "}
          <DeleteIcon />{" "}
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.noteParent {
    width:200px;
    height: 150px;
    position:relative;
}
.note {
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    
}
.note button{
   position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank You E C , your neat trick helped me to make my way out of it <3

Comment: Happy to help:-)